# Meteor for non-real-time webapplication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have been evaluating Meteor for a mostly non-real-time web application, as would like to put less effort for most of housekeeping tasks related to device compatibility, JS compression, etc,. App just has one collection to update real-time to UI, otherwise no need of real-time data sync with UI.

Also will have to integrate the app to sharded MongoDB (already have few TB data), Solr and Memcached.

Is it possible to use Meteor for a kind of AJAX web-application and non-reactive (non-real-time) web application ?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get opinion from Meteor experts if the following solution is a better approach to avoid MongoDB polling and to support sharded MongoDB.

Implemented client server communication using Meteor method calls, and made the returned data available to template thru ReactiveVar / ReactiveDict. With this approach we didn't see any tracing of polling happening, verified it with help of DDP analyzer and MongoDB profiler.